# Why does the fragment stay in the background?he

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I go back to the previous fragment, the fragment it goes from stays in the background, why?

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == rateknap) {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setMessage("Vil du give " + ratingBar.getRating() + " stjerner?")
                .setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Liste.currentForslag.rate(ratingBar.getRating());
                                Db.setDBForslag();
                                launchintent();
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Nej", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();

                            }
                        }
                ).show();


    }
}

private void launchintent() {
    if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else{
        getActivity().finish();
    }
       }
```

I go back from this fragment:
[image: When fragment I go from:]

To this fragment:
[image: This]

EDIT:

This is the fragment I want to go back to

```
        @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Liste.currentForslag = (Forslag)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
        Fragment fragment = new ForslagbeskrivelseFrag();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment, fragment)
                //.addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
```

This is the fragment I remove:

```
   if(v == rateknap){
        Fragment fragment = new RateFrag();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment, fragment)
               .remove(ForslagbeskrivelseFrag.this)
                .commit();
    }
```

Comment: Seems like your showing a dialog over the fragment. When adding fragments use the extra `String tag` in `replace` method. With a unique tag you are then able to query the fragment manager for existing fragments.
`getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String tag)`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because when you committed the fragment transaction you added it to backstack. Remove add to back stack and check again.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have uploaded what I do in the fragment it has to return to

Comment: There is a fragment between them, but I have removed it

Comment: Can you please share how you committed the fragment transaction?

Comment: I will share the one between them and how I removed it

Comment: There is a stack in which all the activities in the running state are kept. Fragments belong to the activity. So you can add them to embed them in a activity.
You can go back to the previous fragment in the backStack with the popBackStack() method. For that you need to add that fragment in the stack using addToBackStack() and then commit() to reflect. This is in reverse order with the current on top. I noticed that you have commented the addtobackstack method, so in your launchIntent method just call getActivity().finish();

Comment: Write Fragment fragment = new ForslagbeskrivelseFrag();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, fragment).addToBackStack("tag").commit(); Then write getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment, fragment)
                .commit();